# What do we know about the strength of the electron-phonon coupling in high-temperature superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, phonons

I would like to clarify the situation of the electron-phonon coupling in high-temperature superconductors (or considering only the cuprates). The main question is what do we know about the strength of the electron-phonon coupling in terms of the experiments. The naive question is that does it exist a universal equation which is an expression of the critical temperature depending on the strength (similar to Mc.Millan formalism), and if it does, is it consistent with the typical ~ 100 K critical temperature of the cuprates.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably aware that the underlying mechanism responsible for superconductivity in cuprates or Fe-based superconductors is still subject to intense debate and research. The usual BCS electron-phonon coupling (EPC) is too weak to account for superconductivity at temperatures of order $100$ K, and produces a gap of s-wave symmetry which is incompatible with the gap symmetry observed in many materials. Several models including [nematicity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1125), [magnetic](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2320) or [spin](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0133) fluctuations, charge and spin density waves... have been proposed, all suported by experimental data.

However, people are still considering the role of EPC in the emergence of superconductivity in the $p$ or $d$-wave channel, such as in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.2697) paper. Its references links to experimental results supporting their idea.

There is also a [nice review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4609) about the possible pairing coming from the Friedel oscillations of the Coulomb potential.

Answer (score 3):

One way to estimate electron-phonon coupling is to take a look on the hot-electron relaxation rate, which can be more or less directly probed by pump-probe spectroscopy. The values for $\lambda$ are around 0.2-0.5. There are few articles on this topic from C. Gadermaier.

Here are the links

http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4726164

http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.257001

http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.011056