# Current State of Research on high $T_c$ Superconductors

Tags: temperature, material-science, superconductivity, ads-cft, phonons

After looking at [these](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.481) two [RevModPhys](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.78.17) articles, I have found myself perplexed by the current state of high $T_c$ superconductivity research. Seeing as I cannot find any SE articles more recent than [5 years](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246367/) or so, I thought I'd ask this question.

What is the current state of research on high-Tc superconductors? In particular, this question I think has two major points, but perhaps an expert can correct me about other angles?

1. Have people managed to rule out electron-phonon interactions as a pairing mechanism? Is there any strong evidence either way?
2. Do we have more conclusive evidence for or against [antiferromagnetic ordering](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mega-magnet-reveals-superconductor-secret-20160222/) contributing to pairing? There seems to more and more discussion about entanglement in the [strange metal](https://www.quantamagazine.org/universal-quantum-phenomenon-found-in-superconductors-20181119/) regime described by holographic conjectures as contributing to a more exotic pairing mechanism? What evidence would you need for this argument?

Comment: "We wanted the paper to represent ... a progress report on where we had gotten so far, the things that could be agreed as a basis for further work. When we submitted it ... we were shocked to discover that although the editor was eager to publish it, he could find only a tiny minority of referees in the field who would agree, ... we did not expect that the field was so poisoned by self-interest and factionalism that no one outside our group could be found who wanted to see such a progress report published." P.W.Anderson, "Personal History ...", 2010.  Same now, methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the problem is much deeper than it seems; the low temperature superconductivity (SC) is poorly understood, so a further evolution in the high temperature SC is locked. The dominating theories cannot explain not only latest facts, such as high-temperature SC, SC in two dimensional systems, SC in heterostructures etc., but also the “conventional” experiments. For example the BCS theory contradicts many effects in conventional metals: inverse/weak/giant isotope effect, Tc dome at high pressure, superconductor-insulator transitions, stable electronic pairs without SC, existence of persistent (for many years!) supercurrents, existence of permanent SC pairs.
A plausible solution of these old questions will open a road to correct solutions for new superconductors.